# Masonry add a loader at the bottom to show more images are still loading

Tags: jquery, append, masonry

I am using masonry to load in lot's of images, I have it setup so that the images gradually load in (append) rather than having lots of white space on the page. You can see working l[ive version here](http://hutchcreative.co.uk/clients/pocko/talent/nomoco/) to help show what I mean.

However as the images are loading in its not very clear if there are still more images to be loaded in. Is it possible to append a loader.gif at the bottom to indicate that more images are still to come? Then once all of the images are loaded the loader.gif disappears.

Here is my jquery:

```
$( function() {
        var $container = $('#artistDetWrap').masonry({
            columnWidth: 1,
            gutter: 0,
            itemSelector: '.artPost'
        });

        // reveal initial images
        $container.masonryImagesReveal( $('#images').find('.artPost') );
    });

    $.fn.masonryImagesReveal = function( $items ) {
        var msnry = this.data('masonry');
        var itemSelector = msnry.options.itemSelector;
        // hide by default
        $items.hide();
        // append to container
        this.append( $items );

        $items.imagesLoaded().progress( function( imgLoad, image ) {
            // get item
            // image is imagesLoaded class, not <img>, <img> is image.img
            var $item = $( image.img ).parents( itemSelector );
            // un-hide item
           $item.show();
            // masonry does its thing
            msnry.appended( $item );
        });

        return this;
    };
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<div id="artistDetWrap" class="entry-content clearfix"></div>

<div id="images">
    <div class="artPost col-lg-6">
        <img width="1170" height="828" alt="dreams_FULL" class="attachment-full" src="myimgsrc.jpg">
    </div>  
</div>
```

---

**Update:**

I have added in the jquery to count images. They are all getting a class of loaded added to them as they load, so this part is working great. However the loader doesn't hide after they have all loaded. Here is my jquery:

```
$.fn.masonryImagesReveal = function( $items ) {
        var totalImage = $('.artPost').length;
        var msnry = this.data('masonry');
        var itemSelector = msnry.options.itemSelector;
        // hide by default
        $items.hide();
        // append to container
        this.append( $items );

        $items.imagesLoaded().progress( function( imgLoad, image ) {
            // get item
            // image is imagesLoaded class, not <img>, <img> is image.img
            var $item = $( image.img ).parents( itemSelector );
            // un-hide item
           $item.show();
            // masonry does its thing
            msnry.appended( $item );
            $item.addClass('loaded');
        });

        if (totalImage == $('.loaded').length)    // if you have other element with loaded class, add more selector to $('.loaded')
        $('#loader').hide();
        return this;
    };
```

Comment: did the image appended continuously without scrolling? and where is the function to know if there are more image to load or not

Comment: Yes the images append without scrolling. It waits for the image to be ready to load then appends it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can try other way to show the loading image in the div before footer from the start like this

```
<div id="contentWrapper">
    <!-- Your Content -->
</div>
<div id="loader">
    <img src="/source/to/loadingimage.gif" />
</div>
<footer>
    <!-- Your Footer -->
</footer>
```

and give css to div `loader`

```
#loader { text-align:center }
```

and when all the image is appended, call

```
$('#loader').hide();
```

### EDIT

count total image in the page that is hidden first

```
var totalImage = $('.artPost').length;
```

add class `loaded` in `$items.imagesLoaded().progress( function( imgLoad, image )` function to declare if the images is already shown like this

```
$items.imagesLoaded().progress( function( imgLoad, image ) {
    // get item
    // image is imagesLoaded class, not <img>, <img> is image.img
    var $item = $( image.img ).parents( itemSelector );
    // un-hide item
    $item.show();
    // masonry does its thing
    msnry.appended( $item );
    $item.addClass('loaded');
});
```

<strike>then before `return this;`</strike> check if total loaded image is the same with total image with class `artPost`, like this

```
if (totalImage == $('.loaded').length)    // if you have other element with loaded class, add more selector to $('.loaded')
    $('#loader').hide();
```

and put it after `$item.addClass('loaded');` inside `$items.imagesLoaded().progress( function( imgLoad, image )` where the image is processed everytime it's loaded

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do I detect if all the images are loaded though?

Comment: where did you get the list of image that will be loaded from? is it already in the html from the start or is it by AJAX

Comment: Its already in the HTML but gets a css class of display:none added by the jquery .hide

Comment: edited the answer, hope that it can help to solve your problem

Comment: Thank you it's almost there! They class of loaded is being added to as the images load however the loader doesn't hide at the end.

Comment: sorry, I got it wrong about the place to put the $('#loader').hide(); put it after $item.addClass('loaded'); rather than on the outside